# Selecting image during Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an outlet called `myImage` for an imageView that is set up with an animation of 5 images.  With a Tap Gesture Recognizer on it, I want to have the users tap on the correct image as it quickly passes to move onto the next level.

There is an error in my code and this does not work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.myImage.animationImages =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"examplePic1.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"examplePic2.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"correctPic.png"],
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"examplePic4.png"],                                 
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"examplePic5.png"],
      nil];

  [self.myImage setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
  self.myImage.animationDuration = 1;
  [self.myImage startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)TapGestureRecognizer:(id)sender {
  if (self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"correctPic.png"]) {
    // Launch next level
  }
  else {
    // Vibrate Device and subtract points from score
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to assign the image (using `=`) in `TapGestureRecognizer` or were you trying to compare it (using `==`)?

Comment: Compare I guess. @MattP, my goal was that when the user taps on the TapGestureRecognizer, if the image is the correct one when they tap it, it launches the next level. Whereas if the user taps on it and 'self.myimage' is not '@"corrrectPic.png" they lose points.

Comment: You are comparing 2 images of type "id". Hence  instead of comparison operator "==" use `isEqual`.

Comment: @jeekOnline When I type this code there is no error but this code does not work. 'if ([self.myImage.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NM17C"]]) {'

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misconception in your code about objects and equality. I assume that you meant `"=="` in your `TapGestureRecognizer` method. However, even if you changed the `=` to `==` would not give you what you want.

The expressions like

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"examplePic1.png"]
```

call a class method of `UIImage` that creates a new UIImage object. You have created 5 of these objects, put them into an array, an set the animationImage array of your `UIImage` object to these images. These objects are all different objects from `myView.image:` I can tell because I can see from your code that you have assigned 5 new objects to the `animationObjects array`. Your `==` test cannot ever work because you are comparing self.image to a brand new `UIImage` object.

What you are trying to do is determine which image the user touched. There is no method in `UIImageView` that tells you which animation `UIImage` is currently showing. You are assuming that the image property of the view will be changed as the animation images are displayed, but there is no reason for this assumption to be true: it is certainly not stated in the documentation. Even if you corrected your code (by doing something like this):

```
if(self.image == [self.animationImages objectAtIndex:2]){

}
```

your code would not be correct.

If I were trying to do what you want, I would create a UIView with 5 `UIImageView` as `subview`, each with their own `gesture recognizer`. I would use the frame property of each `subview` to do my animation.

Comment: Do you mean that I should have 5 UIImageViews and animate each but lets say the fourth one in the sequence is the correct one, so I put the Tap Gesture Recognizer on the fourth ImageView and none on the rest?

Comment: You could do that or you can have the same Tap Gesture Recognizer in each UIImageView, with some logic in the recognizer code to decide if it is the right image.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the options are to determine which image "should" be showing based upon the startTime of the animation.

[Determine which of its animationImages a UIImageView is displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848438/determine-which-of-its-animationimages-a-uiimageview-is-displaying)

Or, just use a timer to set the currently displayed image.

[Detect which image was clicked in UIImageView with animationImages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858028/detect-which-image-was-clicked-in-uiimageview-with-animationimages/12882898#12882898)